# Open source git repo management

Tags: git, github, frameworks, frontend

I maintain a front-end framework called [Kickoff](https://github.com/TryKickoff/kickoff), it is similar in design to Bootstrap or Foundation. We currently maintain one main repo for the framework and another for a Yeoman generator. Our traditional process for updating both repos is write in one ([the framework repo](https://github.com/TryKickoff/kickoff)) and manually copy into the other ([the Yeoman generator](https://github.com/TryKickoff/generator-kickoff)) - this is a painful process to manage to say the least, especially when there's a large release being planned.

I would like to split our codebase up in to much smaller chunks and then import them into both repos, **what would be the best way to do this?** A typical example for this use-case would be a to have the entire Sass folder in its own repo, and then a Sass module like the grid have its own repo too.

We have thought about git submodules, is that a good way to do it; or would another process such as automated/compiled builds be better?

If anyone reading this has experience with this type of thing, I would really appreciate some input.

Answer (score 0):

> A typical example for this use-case would be a to have the entire Sass folder in its own repo, and then a Sass module like the grid have its own repo too

`git submodule` is what you are looking for (as you found out already).

> We have thought about git submodules, is that a good way to do it; or would another process such as automated/compiled builds be better?

---

From [the doc](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html):

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

As explained above the submodule content is fetched form a standalone repository to a folder inside your current repository. Any modification to the submodule folder will not appear in the root folder `git status` on the root folder will not display them.

So to summarize it: submodule is exactly what you need here.

[image]

Comment: Thank you CodeWizard, I will give this another go with submodules.